# Setting up a forward proxy on Google cloud run

Tags: go, proxy, http-proxy, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to set up a [goproxy](https://github.com/elazarl/goproxy) server on [Google cloud run](https://cloud.google.com/run). The go file with the corresponding Dockerfile below are working flawlessly when I run them locally.

Is something like this possible at all? From my limited understanding of proxies, using the `CONNECT` method should work over https. What am I missing here?

#### Go file

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/elazarl/goproxy"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    proxy := goproxy.NewProxyHttpServer()
    proxy.Verbose = true
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":" + os.Getenv("PORT"), proxy))
}
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.14

WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY goproxy.go /go/src/app/goproxy.go

RUN cd /go/src/app && go get -d -v .

CMD go run /go/src/app/goproxy.go
```

Comment: What's your error? Locally and on Cloud Run? if any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Run does not support HTTP `CONNECT` verb.

Your best bet is to make an HTTP reverse proxy (which is not possible with goproxy, or at least [I found](https://github.com/elazarl/goproxy/issues/221#issuecomment-705886611) it to be pretty difficult).